# How to calculate $\int_{P}\sqrt{x+y}d\lambda ^{2}(x,y)$

Tags: integration, analysis, self-learning

Let be $$P=\left \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid 0<x+y<1,0<2x-3y<4 \right \}$$ I wonder how to calculate $$\int_{P}\sqrt{x+y}d\lambda ^{2}(x,y)$$ using $$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\2 &-3 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}$$